# How to mysql escape in magento?

Tags: mysql, magento

I want to escape string in magento, but when I am using `mysql_real_escape_string`, i am getting warning.

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
>   [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.soc.....'

I couldn't find any magento's core mysql escape function. So, what should I do?

Comment: Yes, and still googling to find the answer.

Comment: try: http://forums.cpanel.net/f354/cant-connect-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock-111-a-78444.html
and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38

Answer (score 27):

Use this to escape a string for a query and add the surrounding single quotes:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('default_write')->quote($string);
```

You can look up `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` for further quoting details if needed.

Comment: Thanks, this function is escaping string well. It also adds quotes at start and end of string. I hope it will works now.

Comment: this quote was adding quotes in beginning and at end of string. Then i tested magento without any escaping function and there is no need to escape string. I think magento has default escaping function. my code `($tbl_customer = getMazeTable("customer_entity");
      $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
       ->getConnection('core_read');
      $select = $connection->select()
       ->from($tbl_customer)
       ->where('email=?',$email);) `

Comment: Yes, you don't need to quote `$email`, `Zend_Db` handles that for you. You can mark it as answered beside the answer you want to accept.

Comment: @Vinai any idea if there's any core way to escape characters without quoting? For example, I want to use `\ ` character in a `searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter()` call, but it needs to be escaped to work correctly. Only escaping method I can see being used in core is `\Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::_quote`

Answer (score 10):

I think Magento uses a DB Access layer based on PDO, which handles escaping automatically provided you use bound parameters.  Example from [Using Magento Methods to write Insert Queries with care for SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575160/using-magento-methods-to-write-insert-queries-with-care-for-sql-injection)

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getConnection("core_write");

// Concatenated with . for readability
$query = "insert into mage_example "
       . "(name, email, company, description, status, date) values "
       . "(:name, :email, :company, :desc, 0, NOW())";

$binds = array(
    'name'    => "name' or 1=1",
    'email'   => "email",
    'company' => "company",
    'desc'    => "desc",
);
$write->query($query, $binds);
```

Comment: this is a perfect example of why answering with a link is not a good idea: the link is down.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for keeping my answers honest, I should have known better than to answer with just a link.